# how to get the difference between to columns in sql

Tags: sql

i have a table called stock with columns Tran_id,Trancode,item_id barcode prodqty  made in sql as below. each time an item is sold , a row is added with a trancode of sales and each time an item is produced there is a row added with a trancode of production.i need to get the remaining stock for a particuclar item barcode from this table stock. please help and stranded

```
tran_id trancode    item_id  barcode    item_desc   Packid  Packing prodqty userr   Prodate
1       Production      114 12349090898 cofeekarak   CTN      10xCTN    6   emma    2016-04-05
8       sales           114 12349090898 cofeekarak   CTN      10xCTN    2    emma   2016-04-11
```

Comment: You won't get very far on this site with vague questions like that one, it works best when asking about a specific error. What have you tried so far that failed? Did you succeed into getting the sum of the Production quantities? and the sales quantities? Or is it returning the result of their subtraction that is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sum the quantities, positive if production, negative if sales:

```
select sum(case when trancode = 'sales' then -prodqty else prodqty end)
from stock
where barcode = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  select (qty1.Produced - qty2.Sold) as difference from 
 (select sum(prodqty) as Produced from yourtable where barcode='xxxx') qty1,
 (select sum(prodqty) as Sold from yourtable where bardcode='xxxx')qty2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT item_id, SUM(CASE 
    WHEN trancode = "Production" THEN prodqty 
    WHEN trancode = "sales" THEN -prodqty 
    END) AS remaining_stock
FROM stock
GROUP BY item_id
```